# Javascript convert to date/time format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to change a date/time from `28/06/2018 01:30:20` to look like `2018-06-28 01:30:20`.
I found the example below, I tried to change it according to my needs but I get "Invalid Date".

```js
var now = "2018-06-28 01:30:20";
function toJSDate(dateTime) {
  var dateTime = dateTime.split(" ");
  var date = dateTime[0].split("-");
  var time = dateTime[1].split(":");
  return new Date(date[0], date[1], date[2], time[0], time[1], time[2], 0);
}

var jsDate = toJSDate(now);
var dd = jsDate.toLocaleDateString() + " " + jsDate.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(dd);
```

Please any idea and thanks.

Comment: Why are you juggling Date objects here for what can be done using simple string manipulation? You got this splited into the parts already, so all you need to do is rearrange them in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "28/06/2018 01:30:20"

let date = new Date(str.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g, (_, a, b, c) => c + '-' + b + '-' + a))
console.log(date);
```

You need two things - rearange the date string and change `/` to `-`. You could use a simple string replace instead of the splitting, then create a `new Date()`

Answer (score 1):

If You do not need the functions of the Date object, just rearrange the parts:

**ES6**

```js
    function format(dateStr) {
      const dateTime = dateStr.split(" ");
      const date = dateTime[0].split("-");
      return `${date[0]}-${date[1]}-${date[2]} ${dateTime[1]}`;
    }
    
    console.log(format("2018-06-28 01:30:20"));
    //outputs: 2018-06-28 01:30:20
```

Answer (score 1):

If thats a possible solution for you, you can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Then you can try this:

```
var now = "2018-06-28 01:30:20";

var date = moment(new Date(now)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Now `date` holds the string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.
Also Moment.js is a nice framework to handle date formatting and manipulation.

Note:

You could also do this:

```
var date = moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

But that will be deprecated in a next major release.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
This is works for me.
Changing a date/time from "28/06/2018 01:30:20" to look like "2018-06-28 01:30:20" :

```
function changeFormatDate (dateTime) {
    dateTime = dateTime.split(" ");
    var date = dateTime[0].split("/");
    var time = dateTime[1].split(":");
    return date[2]+"-"+date[1]+"-"+date[0]+" "+time[0]+":"+time[1]+":"+ time[2];
}

function convertStringToDateTime(dateString){
        var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
        var dateArray = reggie.exec(dateString); 
        var dateObject = new Date(
        (+dateArray[1]),
        (+dateArray[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
        (+dateArray[3]),
        (+dateArray[4]),
        (+dateArray[5]),
        (+dateArray[6])
       );
       return dateObject;
 }
```